# cakephp save returns true, no data in database

Tags: cakephp

Cakephp 2.3.5 I have the following record to persist into my database

```
$record => array(
    (int) 0 => '14052V',
    (int) 1 => 'Matthew',
    (int) 2 => 'O’Gorman',
    (int) 3 => '1st Class',
    (int) 4 => ''
),
```

and i save it by calling `$this->save($record, array('validate' => false));`

This saves successfully according to cakephp, and returns the record but the id is missing. However nothing is persisted to the database and there are no records.

If I modify the record to the following:

```
 $record => array(
    (int) 0 => '14052V',
    (int) 1 => 'Matthew',
    (int) 2 => 'OGorman',
    (int) 3 => '1st Class',
    (int) 4 => ''
),
```

Then it saves no problem and returns the id in the array. I have `'encoding' => 'utf8'` configured in my `database.php` file but it still won't save.

What is causing this?

The MYSQL string generated is as follows, which works if you run it manually

```
INSERT INTO `wsp_artworkcrm`.`artworks` (`barcode`, `artworkgroup_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `class`, `teacher`, `modified`, `created`, `user_created`, `user_modified`) VALUES ('*14052V-411*', 866, 'Matthew', 'O’Gorman', '1st Class', '', '2016-07-14 16:26:45', '2016-07-14 16:26:45', 2, 2)
```

Comment: That top record with the modified quote; can you try it with a regular quote instead? `2 => "O'Gorman"`

Comment: I've added the sql string to my question, which if you run manually works

Comment: It _could_ (emphasis on _could_; I'm not familiar with CakePHP) be an issue with that version of CakePHP. I see that it was released July 2013, but the most recent 2.3.x release, 2.3.10, was August 2013. I would consider updating to that version as a start and seeing if that fixes the problem. If it doesn't, consider incrementally migrating your codebase to a more recent CakePHP version (2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8) to 2.8.4 (the latest 2.X release)

Comment: updating to 2.6.8 makes no difference. Would UTF encoding be a factor?

Answer (score 0):

As @ChrisForrence mentioned, I think this is a problem with escaping quotes in php.  You need to escape the single quote here `'O’Gorman'`

You can either use single quotes in double quotes like this `"O'Gorman"` or escape it with a backslash `'O\'Gorman'`

Comment: That's not the problem. I've added this, and the sql string now is the following, but it doesn't fix it `INSERT INTO `wsp_artworkcrm`.`artworks` (`barcode`, `artworkgroup_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `class`, `teacher`, `modified`, `created`, `user_created`, `user_modified`) VALUES ('*14052V-411*', 866, 'Matthew', 'O\'Gorman', '1st Class', '', '2016-07-14 16:50:35', '2016-07-14 16:50:35', 2, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) for the POST data.